# How can I customize the 404 page in a Rails app generated by Faveod Designer?

Tags: code-generation

I'm trying to customize the 404 (Page not Found) html response for an application generated by Faveod Designer.

Could someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is done in the Generated Application itself! Go to `/system_settings/public_files` (or go to `Application Settings` -> `Resources` Panel -> `Public Files`).

There you view all your `public_files` including the `404.html` page :)

PS: when looking for something in Faveod don't hesitate to try to search it in Faveod Designer in the global search localized in the top right corner.
It is deceptively powerful! For instance you can find this settings page by searching `404.html`